# Numbers and their reversals and how close can their product be to the power of $10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I just observed about an hour ago that we have $24 \cdot 42=1008$, in other words that the product of number $24$ with its reversal ($42$) is "close" to the power of $10$.

We have smaller numbers that are when multiplied with its reversal even closer to the power of $10$, for example $3 \cdot 3 =9$ and $4 \cdot 4=16$, after $3$ and $4$, the closest to the power of $10$ when multiplied with its reversal is $24$.

Now to proceed to elementary definitions:

> Define the reversal of the natural number $\alpha$ as the number $rev (\alpha)$ which is obtained by reversing the digits of the number $\alpha$.
>
> Define function $f(\alpha)=|\alpha \cdot rev(\alpha) - 10^{m(\alpha)}|$ where $10^{m(\alpha)}$ is the power of $10$ closest to the number $\alpha \cdot rev(\alpha)$ (if it can happen that $\alpha \cdot rev(\alpha)$ is exactly in the middle between $10^{m(\alpha)}$ and $10^{m(\alpha)-1}$ then always choose bigger (or smaller, since this is not crucial for the question) out of those two (so that $f$ is well-defined)).

With these definitions we have $f(3)=1$ and $f(4)=6$ and $f(24)=f(42)=8$.

The question is:

> Does there exist $\alpha_0 \in \mathbb N \setminus \big(\{2,3,4,24,42\} \bigcup \{10^k:k \in \mathbb N_0\}\big)$ such that we have $f(\alpha_0) \leq 7$?

Perhaps this could be settled with computer search of big enough range, but I do not know could it?

Comment: None below $10^6$.

Comment: None with $m(\alpha) \le 50$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Would it be naive to expect that such $\alpha_0$ does not exist?

Comment: None below $10^9$; in fact the last pair up to $10^9$ that even gets within $100$ of a power of $10$ is $175\cdot571=100000-75$.

Comment: @joriki Thanks. Let me know if you find anything else.